# Unknown encryption string

Tags: encryption, hash, md5

I'm trying to learn about encryption and decryption methods when I faced this string:

```
{MD5}JfnnlDI7RTiF9RgfG2JNCw==
```

MD5 is 16-byte string, so anyone know what type of encryption is this and why there is "{MD5}" ??

Comment: It shows up surprisingly often when you do a Google search for it.

Comment: @Ladadadada That's a little bit disappointing and scary, I must say.

Comment: Hashing and encryption are very different.  Hashing takes input text gives it to a hash function that does a bunch of calculations to make an output of fixed length.  Hashing is one-way and for crypto should not be reversible.  Encryption is different--its recoverable if you have the keys.  You give the input (called the plaintext) and a random-looking encryption key to an encryption function to calculate a ciphertext.  From the ciphertext, you can recover the plaintext if you have the decryption key.  With hashing, you can only keep trying every possible input until you find a match.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It was a fun exercise for me, so +1 for the question.

The `{MD5}` part indicates that the string after it is an MD5 hash. As you can see by the trailing `==`, that means the string has been encoded with Base64. By Base64-decoding it, you get the following in binary

```
00100101 11111001 11100111 10010100 00110010 00111011 01000101 00111000 10000101 11110101 00011000 00011111 00011011 01100010 01001101 00001011
```

By converting that binary to HEX, you get:

```
25 f9 e7 94 32 3b 45 38 85 f5 18 1f 1b 62 4d 0b
```

Remove the spaces and you get

```
25f9e794323b453885f5181f1b624d0b
```

Finally run it through an MD5 rainbow table service (I used [md5rainbow.com](http://www.md5rainbow.com/25f9e794323b453885f5181f1b624d0b)) and you get the original text:

```
123456789
```

Comment: Why go through binary at all? Under Linux or *BSD: `echo JfnnlDI7RTiF9RgfG2JNCw== | base64 -d | hexdump -e '16/1 "%02x" "\n"'` (or `… | od -An -tx1 | tr -d ' '`). Then Google.

Comment: @Gilles We all know that there are tens of ways (1337 or non-1337) to achieve this. If you look at the question again, you'd see why I went step by step and explained the output and input of each step. I could have simply written `123456789` as a comment.